# LocalizationDashboard error in Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-engine4

When in **LocalizationDashboard** I press **Gather text** or **Complile translations**, it gives me an error and warnings:

```
Error: LoadConfig (/Script/Engine.Default__RendererSettings): import failed for bEnableAlphaChannelInPostProcessing in: False
Warning: In asset 'None', there is an enum property of type 'EDepthOfFieldMethod' with an invalid value of '('
Warning: Package '/Game/Levels/BigWallBottom' and '/Game/Levels/BigWall' have the same localization ID (764D6BBD47E8990F8B3974AF1C019ECF)
Please reset one of these (Asset Localization -> Reset Localization ID) to avoid conflicts
Warning: Package '/Game/Levels/BigWallTop' and '/Game/Levels/BigWall' have the same localization ID (764D6BBD47E8990F8B3974AF1C019ECF)
Please reset one of these (Asset Localization -> Reset Localization ID) to avoid conflicts
```

I have no idea how to fix error and where should I do this: **Asset Localization -> Reset Localization ID**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the asset mentioned in the Content Browser, right-click -> Asset Localization -> Reset Localization ID

[image: Reset Localization ID via the Content Browser]